# iPhone detecting Bluetooth Device

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using the HeartMonitor example for CoreBluetooth, with a iPhone 5.

Right now I have a Bluetooth 4.0 dongle (bought off ebay), in the Dongle settings I set it as a headset. I am able to see/pair this in the iPhone Bluetooth settings in the iPhone. However using the HeartMonitor sample code (adjusted UUID option to Nil) but I'm unable to see any devices scanned. I've also tried UUID 180A (broadcast profile), 1108 (headset) and various others but no luck.

```
- (void) startScanningForUUIDString:(NSString *)uuidString
{
    [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did not put the options to nil.
I did use a NSDictionnary: `NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:FALSE], CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];`
Don't forget to use the `CentralManager`.